# c# - How to allow specific class call specific method

Tags: c#, class, methods

In my code i need to allow only class **EchoProcess** call method **GetStorePrivateData** from class **MainData**.I thnk it not better way but in this code it work done.How should i do?

** In future  class **MainData** will have more protected class and allow specific other class to call it.

```
internal sealed class EchoProcess : MainData
{
    private EchoProcess()
    {
    }

    public static string EchoPrivate(string someCondition)
    {
        var result = GetStorePrivateData<EchoProcess, Key>();
        //Condition here >
        return "";
    }

    private class Key
    {

    }
}

internal class MainData
{
    protected MainData()
    {
    }

    private static readonly List<string> StorePrivateData = new List<string>();

    protected static List<string> GetStorePrivateData<TEcho, TKey>() where TEcho : class where TKey : class
    {
        return CheckAllowGetStorePrivateDataClassAccess<TEcho, TKey>() ? StorePrivateData : null;
    }

    private static bool CheckAllowGetStorePrivateDataClassAccess<TEcho, TKey>()
    {
        var thisClass = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;
        var echoProcessType = typeof(TEcho);
        var isEchoProcess = echoProcessType.Name == "EchoProcess";
        var keyType = typeof(TKey);
        var isKey = keyType.Name == "Key";
        var isEqualNameSpace = thisClass.Namespace.Equals(echoProcessType.Namespace) &&
                               keyType.Namespace.Equals(echoProcessType.Namespace);
        var keyTypeFullName = $"{echoProcessType.FullName}+{keyType.Name}";
        var isEqulaKeyTypeNameSpace = keyType.FullName.Equals(keyTypeFullName);
        return isEqualNameSpace && isEqulaKeyTypeNameSpace && isEchoProcess && isKey;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> In my code I need to allow only class `EchoProcess` call method `GetStorePrivateData` from class `MainData`.

**Do not do any of this stuff with reflection or stack traces**.

Both types are `internal`.  They're in the same assembly. Mark the method you wish to restrict callers on as `internal`.  Now any code in your assembly can call that method. **Who cares? You wrote that code; if you don't like it, you can change it.**

This is a problem that should be solved by communicating with the coders who are writing the assembly about what the correct protocols are for using assembly implementation details. This is an *interpersonal team relationships* problem, so don't try to solve it by writing code. Mark the method as internal, and if there's a call site that you don't like, then *talk to the developer who wrote it during code review to find out why they thought that was a good idea.*

Comment: See [friend assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk(v=vs.110).aspx), which can access internals.

Comment: @JohnWu: Right, and *you control who your friends are*.  If your friends are calling methods that you don't want them to call, **tell them about that in code review**. If they're being bad actors, then why are they your friends? If they're being good actors, then you can trust them to follow your guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

> In future class MainData will have more protected class and allow specific other class to call it.

Glad to hear it... the solution I provide below isn't ideal (e.g. you won't get any errors at compile time), and there are object models that are probably better suited for this.

> In my code i need to allow only class EchoProcess call method GetStorePrivateData from class MainData.I thnk it not better way but in this code it work done.How should i do?

It is pretty easy to write code that inspects the call stack (you can obtain a copy with `var s = new StackTrace()` and walk the stack with `s.GetFrames()`). You can walk the call stack and see if `EchoProcess` was the caller or if the call came from somewhere else. Here is a simple example:

```
static public class CallPermissionHelper
{
    static public bool IsAllowed<T>() where T : class
    {
        var callers = new StackTrace()
            .GetFrames()
            .Select
            (
                f => f.GetMethod().DeclaringType
            );
        var immediateCaller = callers.ElementAt(1);
        var firstOutsideCaller = callers
            .Skip(2)
            .Where
            (
                t => t != immediateCaller 
            )
            .FirstOrDefault();
        return (firstOutsideCaller == typeof(T));
    }
}
```

The logic is straightforward:

1. Obtain a list of callers, derived from the stack trace.
2. Ignore the first frame (which references the current code location, not very helpful)
3. Check the second frame to determine the class that called our helper class.  In our case it will be `MainData`. We can ignore any stack frames from this class, e.g. if it is calling itself or using utility functions, since obviously it has permission to call itself.
4. Check the rest of the frames for any other classes, working down the stack. If the first class we run into is `EchoProcess`, we return true. In all other cases we return false.

Here is how to use it in your example:

```
internal sealed class EchoProcess : MainData
{
    private class Key {}

    public static string GetPrivateFromMainData()
    {
        return MainData.GetStorePrivateData<EchoProcess, Key>();
    }
}

internal class MainData
{
    public static string GetStorePrivateData<TEcho, TKey>() where TEcho : class where TKey : class
    {
        var allowed = CallPermissionHelper.IsAllowed<EchoProcess>();  //Magic!!!
        return allowed ? "Allowed" : "Blocked";
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = EchoProcess.GetPrivateFromMainData();
        var b = MainData.GetStorePrivateData<object, object>();

        Console.WriteLine("a={0}", a);
        Console.WriteLine("b={0}", b);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a=Allowed
b=Blocked
```

[See my code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KiGLLM)